# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

***Activity1.class***

```
   public class CategoryActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {  

    private RelativeLayout mReLayout;  
    private byte[] mImageByte;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);  
        addControl();  
        addEventOnClick();  
        mReLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
    }
    private void addEventOnClick() {
        findViewById(R.id.layout_category_1).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void addControl() {

        mReLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_category);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.layout_category_1:
                startActivity();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void startActivity() {
        Bitmap layoutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mReLayout.getWidth(), mReLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(layoutBitmap);
        mReLayout.draw(canvas);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        layoutBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bStream);
        mImageByte = bStream.toByteArray();
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
        mIntent.putExtra(Constant.BYTE_IMAGE, mImageByte);
        startActivity(mIntent);

    }
    }
```

Activity2.class

```
OnCreate

byte[] mImageByte=getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray(Constant.BYTE_IMAGE);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mImageByte, 0, mImageByte.length);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

When I click `onClickListener.` It show bug :  FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
Please. Help me!

Comment: kindly post complete stack trace!

Comment: I mean logcat stack!

Comment: When I click Button. It not start Activity. And Logcat show

03-15 16:50:36.257 11916-11916/com.bct E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: Ok, there is a limit on the size of the extra you put through intent (I guess 1 mb). `mImageByte` size is large that's why you are getting the exception.

Comment: Can you give fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason is you're trying to put a Bitmap as an Intent extra. Although it's theoretically possible, I think the size of the Image limits such possibilities.

If you want to pass an image to another activity, then first

- Save the Bitmap to a file
- Send the filepath as a String to the next activity
- Use the filepath from the next activity to recreate the Bitmap

If that is difficult, then try using a Singleton to store a Bitmap temporarily in memory.

Here's how to save it to disk.

First add the permission in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then...

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "imageBitmap" + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
```

Now send the filename to the next activity.

```
mIntent.putExtra("filename", "imageBitmap");
```

On the next activity, recreate the bitmap.

```
String fName = getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fName + ".png"
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do u mean a sample of how to save a Bitmap?

Comment: Can you help me fix it. I want save Layout view as image ??